# How to have a different virtual desktop per physical display?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, design, virtualdesktop

**Context:**

- I've recently switched back to using an external monitor with my laptop.
- I'm using a 2x2 virtual desktop with the expo plugin. (Actually a 3x3, doesn't matter)
- I'm currently not satisfied with the associated workflow.

**What it currently looks like:**

[image]

As you can see there are 2x2 virtual desktops, each virtual desktop being a wall of the different physical displays.

**What it could look like:**

[image]

The picture is [extracted from the video of a 2011 design mockup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbwNMnNUGFA), the obvious difference being that there is one different virtual desktop per physical display.

I had no problem to keep track of where wy windows are using only one screen but it's suddenly more difficult to manage with a second screen. (Not to mention that plugging it moves my windows arounds the different virtual desktops...)

- What happened to the mockup ?
- How do I get different virtual desktops per physical display
  as showed in the mockup ?
- Is it even currently possible ? Can I code it ?